# Como alterar a posição no mapa cada vez que o usuário clicar em um link?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Eu preciso exibir um mapa e logo abaixo teria uma lista com múltiplos endereços e ao clicar em cada endereço seria marcado no Google Maps o lugar. Já dei uma pesquisada na net mas não achei nada que eu pudesse me basear.

Comment: O que você está construindo? Uma página da web? Um app? Uma aplicação desktop?

Comment: É em um site. A empresa tem escritório em várias cidades diferentes e para mostrar onde se encontra cada escritório queria fazer dessa forma. Mas não estou conseguindo achar nada na net que possa me ajudar.

Comment: Você já consegue criar o mapa e só falta centralizar? Qual é o código que já tem pronto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este é o exemplo de um mapa básico que faz parte da [documentação do Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Esse código cria um objeto `map`, do tipo [`google.maps.Map`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map). Para mudar o centro, basta chamar o `setCenter` desse objeto, passando latitude e logitude. Esses valores podem ser definidos:

1. Como um [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng):

   ```
   var posicao = new google.maps.LatLng(-35, 151);
   ```
2. Ou como um objeto literal:

   ```
   var posicao = {lat: -34, lng: 151};
   ```

Com isso, basta passar a posição para centralizar:

```
map.setCenter(posicao);
```

Comment: Mas como posso manipular isso? E adicionar outros valores? Basicamente o que preciso fazer é assim: http://jsfiddle.net/dUMFW/5/

Comment: Cada link desse deve conter um endereço diferente e mudar lá no mapa e é exatamente isso que não estou conseguindo fazer.

Comment: Bom, agora o @rrnan já explicou essa parte, então não vou adicionar aqui. Mas você poderia ter esclarecido isso de cara na pergunta, não? Pelo que você escreveu lá, não dava pra saber onde exatamente estava sua dificuldade.

Comment: desculpa ter interpretado mal, não sabia exatamente como explicar isso.

Comment: @AltembergAndrade E me desculpe se meu comentário soou desrespeitoso. É que aqui no site nós gostamos que as perguntas sejam bem claras e objetivas, focadas. Assim, uma pergunta e suas respostas acabam tendo utilidade pra muito mais gente além de quem originalmente perguntou. Portanto por favor leve isso em conta na próxima pergunta ok? E bom aprendizado :)

Answer (score 4):

Uma forma é definindo a latitude e longitude com atributos `data-*`. Você pode ter um elemento `<a>` com a seguinte marcação:

```
<a href='#' data-latitude='-xx.xxx' data-longitude='-yy.yyy'>Endereço, 123</a>
```

Utilizando JavaScript você pode obter essas duas informações. Um exemplo simples, com jQuery:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
   var lat = $(this).data('latitude'),
       lon = $(this).data('longitude');

       alert("Latitude: " + lat + ". Longitude: " + lon);
});
```

E então criar uma nova localização para o Google Maps.

```
meuMapa.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon));
```

---

#### Segue um código de exemplo:

```js
$(function () {
  
  var $map = $("#map-view").get(0),
 
  // latitude e longitude inicial
  latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(28.617161,77.208111);
  
  var gmap = new google.maps.Map($map, {
    center: latlon,
    zoom: 10
  });
  
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlon,
    map: gmap,
    title: 'Rajya Sabha'
  });
                
  
  $('.map-nav a').on('click', function(){
    var lat = $(this).data('lat'),
        lon = $(this).data('lon');
    
    // obtem a nova latitude/longitude
    var newLatLon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
    
    gmap.panTo(newLatLon); // muda a posição do mapa pra nova localização
    marker.setPosition(newLatLon); // altera a posição do marcador
    marker.setTitle($(this).html()) // altera o título do marcador
  });
});
```

```css
/* Somente para melhorar a visualização */
#map-view{ width: 100%; height: 250px }
.map-nav {width: 100%; background: #333; padding: 8px 0; text-align:center}
.map-nav a{ text-decoration: none; color: #fff;margin: 0 15px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp'></script>

<nav class='map-nav'>
  <a href='#' data-lat='-3.11903' data-lon='-60.02173'>Manaus, AM</a>
  <a href='#' data-lat='-25.42895' data-lon='-49.26714'>Curitiba, PR</a>
  <a href='#' data-lat='-12.97304' data-lon='-38.50230'>Salvador, BA</a>
</nav>
<div id='map-view'></div>
```

---

[Data Attributes <sup>[W3C]</sup>](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)
[Data Attributes <sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Comment: Você poderia trocar o jQuery por JS puro? A pergunta não menciona jQuery.

Comment: @bfavaretto Por isso que boa parte do código está escondido, pensei que a questão era a lógica de como fazer e minha sugestão foi: data attributes.

Comment: Entendo. Meu receio é que isso acabe induzindo outras pessoas a usar jQuery só para resolver algo assim (claro que quando a biblioteca já está em uso no projeto para outros fins, faz mais sentido usá-la também nesse caso, mas não sabemos a situação do AP nem de outros futuros leitores).

Comment: Talvez eu esteja exagerando ao tentar proteger o mundo do excesso de jquerização da web :)